# Woocommerce Tabs Conditional

Tags: if-statement, woocommerce, conditional-statements

I running the Woocommerce plugin ( Version 2.013) with Woocommerce Tab Manager extension (Version 1.08). Also Canvas Child Theme (Version 0.1.0)

I'm trying only show certain tabs for certain products using a conditional statement.

The tab manager doesn't allow conditional statements for each tab. It only allows default global tabs or product specific tabs assigned in the product edit page.

I found a decent way to show tabs in the product page based on the a product attribute.

First I thought I share this code because it seems to work. But I'm still wondering if there is a better way to do this?

What I would really like is to create a tab in the Tab Manager and apply the conditional statement to it.

```
// Video Tabs for Product Page - Activate New Video Tab if Attribute matches
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'video_tab' );
function video_tab( $tabs ) {
    $type = array_shift(woocommerce_get_product_terms($_product->id, 'pa_type', 'names'));  
    if ( $type == "TypeA" ) {
    $video_tab = array( 'video_tab' =>  array( 'title' => $type.' Video', 'priority' => 9, 'callback' => 'video_tab_func' ) );      
    return array_merge( $video_tab, $tabs );
    }
        else {
            return $tabs;   
        }
}

// Tab Desctribtion         
function video_tab_func() {
    $type = array_shift(woocommerce_get_product_terms($_product->id, 'pa_type', 'names'));  
    if ( $type == "TypeA" ) {
    echo do_shortcode( '[video src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/TypeA-video.mp4"]' );
    }
}
```